# Running hybrid python/c++ code in gdb

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I have a system that uses both c++ and python codes. For example I want to run python script which calls c++ function. I want to run this python script in gdb (or any possible debuger) and step into c++ function it calls. I found this:

```
gdb -ex r --args python <programname>.py <arguments>
```

, but the whole system runs till its end. I would like it to stop in the beginning of the `<programname>.py` code, and then I would use gdb commands like next or step. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  To start GDB:

```
gdb --args python <programname>.py <arguments>
```

Then you'll be inside GDB, and can do `start` to launch the program and then step through it, set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Yes, I tried to run the program this way, but it executes till its end so I don't know when to set breakpoints etc. Normally inside gdb when I run the program it stops on its beginning and waits to some commands. This won't stop and wait but simply runs.

Comment: You're saying when you issue the GDB command `start` that it runs the program to completion??  What if you just `gdb --args python --help`?

Comment: It gives this: `Reading symbols from python...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/bin/python2.7...done.
done.
(gdb)` and waits.

Comment: It runs the program before a can type `start`.